# implementing BigPipe for .NET to improve performance

Tags: .net, performance, scalable

a very cool [article](http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/bigpipe-pipelining-web-pages-for-high-performance/389414033919) on how facebook breaks up their page into "pagelets" to maximize the work done by the server and browser when building a complex page that grabs various resources (ads, feeds, friends, etc).  they call it bigpipe.

[steve souders](http://stevesouders.com/) actually talked about this at one of his talks and he referred to it as "flushing the document early".

in .NET, you can't easily do this, but i have done it by overriding the render method and flushing response buffer early, so it's possible and it works pretty good. but i never tried it at this large scale.  my question is, is it feasible to build a BigPipe in .NET? they said they built theirs in java and PHP.  i think it can be done in .NET as well, but i'm wondering if the .NET winforms architecture might be suboptimal for doing something like this.

i'm considering pushing a project at our company to build something like this - but will need to do plenty of more research because this won't be a small project.  i'd like to build something that could support breaking up ANY arbitrary page into these "pagelets".  in .NET it might be nice to be able to turn our custom user controls into these "pagelets" and "flush" them all out in chunks - bigpipe style.

comments/thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented a version of BigPipe in an ASP.Net MVC web project, by early flushing and executing pagelets content in parallel. You can read it on [How To Implement BigPipe Using ASP.Net MVC](http://blog.josemanuelperez.es/2010/09/tutorial-bigpipe-asp-net-mvc-facebook/) and fork it on [GitHub](https://github.com/JMPerez/BigPipe).

This technique is easy to apply if you implement pagelets as PartialViews that are executed at the end of the HTML document, just before closing `<body>` section.

In addition, if you want to take full advantage of BigPipe, you should load the Javascript and CSS needed by the pagelets in a certain sequence, providing the best user experience. BigPipe loads CSS resources in parallel prior to injecting the HTML of the pagelet in the page and, when every pagelet has been injected, it proceeds to Javascript parallel download and execution.

Comment: Hello Jose, if you have the time I would appreciate a quick word with you. I am following your tutorial right now and attempting to implement bigpipe in my mvc project but my pagelets keep rendering before my parent view/layout does. Does this sound like something obvious? I've tried taking a look at your sample project but it does not open with VS 2013

Comment: Hi @Adrian did you managed to get this solution working ? I am also trying to get it working.

Comment: Yes I did. What are you having trouble with?